# Adding an extra column in the sharepoint list preview viewstyle

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I am using the Out-Of-The-Box preview viewstyle for displaying a list. My requirement is to display and extra column on the left side of the the view, along with the title column. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there is no easy, SUPPORTED way to do this.  You would have to modify the preview ViewStyle (as defined in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML\VWSTYLES.XML) to display your column.  Now this can certainly be done - display CAML is painful but not impossible, but it would modify the preview viewstyle on your entire sharepoint install.  See http://mo.notono.us/search?q=viewstyle for more info

Another way to do this MAY be through javascript (I'd use jQuery), though I am not entirely sure HOW you'd accomplish it. I do know Paul over at EndUserSharePoint.com has done some amazing things with client side script...

Answer (score 1):

You may add the extra column by modifying the default view. To do this, you should see on the right-top corner of the list, a view that is "View all". 
- Click on that tag and choose from the drop-down menu "Modify current view". 
- You will be taken to a form that allows you to choose which columns you want (or don't want) to be displayed on the "default" view.
- (you have also options to sort, filter, etc... this view attending to your needs).

Also, from the drop-down I mentioned, you can create a "new view" instead of modifying the default one, and then, in the list settings, you are allowed to choose which between all the available views, will be the default one.

Hope this helps...

Comment: The preview view style shows only the title column at first, no matter how many columns are chosen in the view. When you hover over an item in the displayed column,it shows the rest of the columns in a preview pane. http://tinyurl.com/6kcbaw

Comment: Oh, my fault! I totally missed out the "preview" part :-) I'll check out and come back if I find a solution...